# sql large data reading

Tags: c#, sql

I have to read an sql table with about 100 columns and then check each cell to verify if the data is not null. Using SQLReader it throws me an IndexOutOfBoundsOfArrway exception at column no 70. Any ideea how shold I reach my goal?
P.S. I am doing this in c#

This is my code:

```
conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( "select * from tableName where column1='" + 
                                 textBox1.Text+"'", conn);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
   for (int i = 3; i < 100; i++)
   {
      if (reader[i].ToString() != "")
      {
          listBox2.Items.Add(reader[i].ToString());
      }

    }
 }
```

EDIT: I am sure that my table has 100 column, but reader.FieldCount is equal to 70

Comment: are you sure that are exactly 100 columns? Because this errors should mean that column are 69 (i think). Have you check in Property FieldsColumn to know exactly no of Columns exposed by DataReader? For should be like this: for(int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount;...)

Comment: You should also consider reading about [SqlParameter](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter)

Comment: The 'if (reader[i].ToString' ...  Should be 'if (reader[i] != null'

Comment: @Kane: or if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(reader[i]))...

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this more dynamic approach, it will work no matter the amount of columns:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
   // not sure  why you started at 3, 
   // this code is generic so it will also work for tables with less that 3 columns
   // but maybe that is something you can omit
   for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount ; i++)
   {
      if (reader[i] == null)
         continue;

      listBox2.Items.Add(reader[i].ToString());      
   }
}
```

You might also want to consider moving the null check out of the actual reading procedure since looping through the columns takes a considerable amount of time and your blocking the reader while you do so.

However depending on the amount of rows your reading in this might introduce new challenges in regards to memory consumption.

**UPDATE**
In order to avoid retrieving each column separately by index, use the `GetValues()` batch operation of the `DataReader` instead that returns an object array of all values, also if you expect just one line, use if rather than while to avoid issues:

```
if (reader.Read())
{
  var values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
  reader.GetValues(values);

  for (int i = 0; i < values.Count ; i++)
  {
    if (values[i] == null)
       continue;  
    listBox2.Items.Add(values[i].ToString());      
  }
}
```

Comment: I always read only one row and I start at 3 becouse columns 0,1 and 2 have some ID values that I work with elsewhere...It is possible that if I have too many columns , the sqlDataReader to be limited at the first 70 columns?

Comment: This depends on when the exception is raised. If the exception is raised in the `reader.Read()` line than the issue seems to be some kind of limit in the DataReader, but if the exceptions is raised later in the code the reader already holds the data in an internal array so the issue would have to be in your code. However as far as I remember I have never come across a column limit in the DataReader and I have worked with similar large tables in the past.

Answer (score 3):

A DataReader has the following property column
information:

```
FieldCount - returns the number of columns in the result set.
```

use it and first check you are getting 100 columns or not.

**Read :** [**`SqlDataReader.FieldCount`** Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.fieldcount.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a for loop on each row, you could instead do a foreach on each column in the row.
That would prevent this issue, and the column count wouldn't be hardcoded into your code.